# rails 5: Dynamic form fields generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails.Currently i am working on a project in which i have three models **wholesaler**, **application_template**, and template fields.A wholesaler can create an application_template in which he/she specifies the application fields(by selecting data_type and typing field name)
[application_fields form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCWJR.png)
that would be included in the application_template.
It is working perfectly, but the problem is now i want to store conditional inputs e.g wholesaler wants to specify a field which is required incase if applicant age > 40.

I have searched and go through different documentations but i could not found any solution to store these conditions in db. and then show conditional fields in application form . Can anyone please help me? 
i am using pgsql as db

Comment: You should provide some code we could help you with.

Comment: @HoloHokkaido sorry for not replying earlier, i have solved the issue. Thankyou

Comment: You should post the answer you have found in order to help people who wonder the same.